# Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException

Tags: java

[image: [img]http://i.imgur.com/5Zm9O6I.png[/img]]

I get this error ! I don't know how to solve.Please help me !

[image: [img]http://i.imgur.com/9V80hSY.png[/img]]

Comment: please edit your question and add the relevant code parts

Comment: Include the code and stacktrace as >>text<< not as images on some temporary image drop site.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Answer (score 1):

You are increasing j instead of decreasing. It should be:

```
for(j=i;j>0;j--)
```

Or you should go by the actual stack size:

```
while (s.size()>0)
```